All USB ports (3.0 and C) suddenly stopped working after using ADB
On Ubuntu 22.04 (edit, I just upgraded to 24.04 as a desperate move, it did not solve my issue) on an HP laptop, I was flashing an Android device using adb sideload and my laptop was not connected to AC (so, running on battery). At some point when I reconnected the phone to transfer the data, it was not connecting (= not even charging, both the computer and the phone states were exactly as if no cable was between them). I tried with another cable, another phone, then simply with my mice, basically no device can be connected with USB anymore to my laptop. I rebooted the computer, no changes.
At that point, I suspected something with power management disabling my USB ports. I forced it from "auto" to "on" in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/level for both usb1 and usb2, that did not fix anything. I checked dmesg without noticing anything weird. I tried to install a more recent 6.11 kernel (I am running the official 6.8 at the moment), no improvements.
How can I know if my USB ports are disabled?
Output of lsusb:
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:5374 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Output of usb-devices:
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh=12
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=06.11
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 6.11.11-061111-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=09 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0026 Rev=00.02
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  64 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=1ms

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=10000 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 3.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=06.11
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 6.11.11-061111-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

Ouput of sudo dmesg | grep -a5 hub
[    0.541273] iommu: DMA domain TLB invalidation policy: lazy mode
[    0.541273] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.541273] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.541273] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.541273] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.541273] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.541273] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.541273] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.541273] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.541273] PTP clock support registered
[    0.541781] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
--
[    1.811813] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.11
[    1.811820] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.811822] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.811824] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.11.11-061111-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.811827] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.812064] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.812099] hub 1-0:1.0: 12 ports detected
[    1.815230] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.11
[    1.815235] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.815237] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.815239] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 6.11.11-061111-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.815240] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.817087] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.817126] hub 2-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.831400] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.832610] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:6b:00.0
[    1.833162] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    1.833376] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SPD Write Disable is set
[    1.833428] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus using PCI interrupt

Output of sudo dmesg | grep -a5 usb
[    0.541273] iommu: Default domain type: Translated
[    0.541273] iommu: DMA domain TLB invalidation policy: lazy mode
[    0.541273] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.541273] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.541273] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.541273] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.541273] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.541273] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.541273] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.541273] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.541273] PTP clock support registered
[    0.541781] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.542061] efivars: Registered efivars operations
--
[    1.809907] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.811107] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000000009810
[    1.811697] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.811704] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.811709] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    1.811813] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 6.11
[    1.811820] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.811822] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.811824] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 6.11.11-061111-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.811827] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.812064] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.812099] hub 1-0:1.0: 12 ports detected
[    1.815230] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.11
[    1.815235] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.815237] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.815239] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 6.11.11-061111-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.815240] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.817087] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.817126] hub 2-0:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.831400] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.832610] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:6b:00.0
[    1.833162] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
--
[    1.866318] intel-lpss 0000:00:15.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    1.866731] idma64 idma64.1: Found Intel integrated DMA 64-bit
[    2.012133] input: SYNA30B3:00 06CB:CE08 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-SYNA30B3:00/0018:06CB:CE08.0001/input/input5
[    2.012331] input: SYNA30B3:00 06CB:CE08 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-SYNA30B3:00/0018:06CB:CE08.0001/input/input7
[    2.012538] hid-generic 0018:06CB:CE08.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [SYNA30B3:00 06CB:CE08] on i2c-SYNA30B3:00
[    2.053311] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.205517] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0408, idProduct=5374, bcdDevice= 0.06
[    2.205522] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    2.205523] usb 1-2: Product: HP HD Camera
[    2.205524] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Quanta
[    2.205525] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[    2.321331] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.448970] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0026, bcdDevice= 0.02
[    2.448973] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.538980] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Found COMETLAKE/ULT (device ID 9b41) display version 9.00
[    2.539740] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] VT-d active for gfx access
[    2.554936] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    2.554983] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Using Transparent Hugepages
[    2.557148] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
--
[   12.893679] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain dram
[   12.893680] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain psys
[   12.908827] Adding 1003516k swap on /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1.  Priority:-3 extents:1 across:1003516k SS
[   12.918506] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   12.958858] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
[   12.959372] usb 1-2: Found UVC 1.00 device HP HD Camera (0408:5374)
[   12.962479] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[   12.962582] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): mounted filesystem b8cbe49e-bf8f-4842-a75c-e1859e15b670 r/w with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[   12.964020] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   13.028019] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 34:c9:3d:78:86:ce
[   13.057355] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   13.074613] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi
[   13.074761] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x24800
[   13.074764] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 206-22.23
[   13.074767] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[   13.078298] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.

Full details: sudo lsusb -s 002:001 -v
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               3.10
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         3 
  bMaxPacketSize0         9
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0003 3.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            6.11
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 6.11.11-061111-generic xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:14.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x001f
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
        bMaxBurst               0
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              12
  bDescriptorType      42
  nNbrPorts             6
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       50 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  bHubDecLat          0.0 micro seconds
  wHubDelay             0 nano seconds
  DeviceRemovable    0x00
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
   Port 2: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
   Port 3: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
   Port 4: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
   Port 5: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
   Port 6: 0000.02a0 lowspeed L1
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
  bLength                 5
  bDescriptorType        15
  wTotalLength       0x005b
  bNumDeviceCaps          2
  SuperSpeed USB Device Capability:
    bLength                10
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType      3
    bmAttributes         0x02
      Latency Tolerance Messages (LTM) Supported
    wSpeedsSupported   0x0008
      Device can operate at SuperSpeed (5Gbps)
    bFunctionalitySupport   1
      Lowest fully-functional device speed is Full Speed (12Mbps)
    bU1DevExitLat          10 micro seconds
    bU2DevExitLat         918 micro seconds
  SuperSpeedPlus USB Device Capability:
    bLength                76
    bDescriptorType        16
    bDevCapabilityType     10
    bmAttributes         0x000000ef
      Sublink Speed Attribute count 15
      Sublink Speed ID count 7
    wFunctionalitySupport   0x1106
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[0]   0x00050034
      Speed Attribute ID: 4 5Gb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[1]   0x000500b4
      Speed Attribute ID: 4 5Gb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[2]   0x000a4035
      Speed Attribute ID: 5 10Gb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeedPlus
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[3]   0x000a40b5
      Speed Attribute ID: 5 10Gb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeedPlus
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[4]   0x00e00026
      Speed Attribute ID: 6 224Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[5]   0x00e000a6
      Speed Attribute ID: 6 224Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[6]   0x00c00027
      Speed Attribute ID: 7 192Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[7]   0x00c000a7
      Speed Attribute ID: 7 192Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[8]   0x00800028
      Speed Attribute ID: 8 128Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[9]   0x008000a8
      Speed Attribute ID: 8 128Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[10]   0x00b10029
      Speed Attribute ID: 9 177Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[11]   0x00b100a9
      Speed Attribute ID: 9 177Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[12]   0x0063002a
      Speed Attribute ID: 10 99Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[13]   0x006300aa
      Speed Attribute ID: 10 99Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[14]   0x00c6002b
      Speed Attribute ID: 11 198Mb/s Symmetric RX SuperSpeed
    bmSublinkSpeedAttr[15]   0x00c600ab
      Speed Attribute ID: 11 198Mb/s Symmetric TX SuperSpeed
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered

sudo lsusb -s 001:001 -v
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Single TT
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct          0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice            6.11
  iManufacturer           3 Linux 6.11.11-061111-generic xhci-hcd
  iProduct                2 xHCI Host Controller
  iSerial                 1 0000:00:14.0
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0019
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower                0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0004  1x 4 bytes
        bInterval              12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength              11
  bDescriptorType      41
  nNbrPorts            12
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
    TT think time 8 FS bits
  bPwrOn2PwrGood       10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent      0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable    0x04 0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask    0xff 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0507 highspeed power suspend enable connect
   Port 3: 0000.0100 power
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0100 power
   Port 7: 0000.0100 power
   Port 8: 0000.0100 power
   Port 9: 0000.0100 power
   Port 10: 0000.0107 power suspend enable connect
   Port 11: 0000.0100 power
   Port 12: 0000.0100 power
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered


It sounds like no power to the USB's. Check the BIOs and see what it reports. (It is possible the BIOs monitors such things.) Depending on the rig it might be an over voltage device that will stay asserted until the power is removed. I am not sure how to fix this with a battery device.  You could try draining the main battery and then recharging provided it doesn't damage it. On the other hand it might be a fuse on the mother board which would be problematic to change I would image. It is likely it will be a surface mount soldered in device. Worse might be damage to USB driver chip.
